# Notification Center - Can you replace the bullet icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm trying to replace the blue bullet icon in the notification center for my app.

I thought that `alertLaunchImage` would allow me to do this. I have tried doing something like

```
not.alertLaunchImage = @"customBullet";
```

but it keeps the default blue bullet. Is the bullet customizable at all?

Update

In the screenshot below, i'm trying to customize the blue bullet on the left. I know already how to customize the main image (in this case the gmail icon)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that little dot appearing below the header of an app's notification? If yes I don't think so, it's a system image which is applied to almost every notification

Comment: When you receive a notification the application icon gets used in the notification panel. Are you trying to get two different images?

Comment: updated my question with a graphic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. It just means "new message" and it's managed by the system, not the apps.